# How to repeat countdown timer a certain number of times

Tags: java, android, timer

I want to to repeat my countdown timer a certain number of times but I don't know how to do it. I am using Handler and runnable function but my countdown timer repeats an infinite number of times when I want to set, for example, only 4 times my display look like this (where 4 is number of rounds that I wanna repeat):

[image: my display].

Here is my code:

```java
Button btn1;
TextView tv1;

EditText et1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv1=findViewById(R.id.textView);
    btn1=findViewById(R.id.button);
    et1=findViewById(R.id.editText);

    String edit1=et1.getText().toString();
    //number of rounds

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CountDownTimer countDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    tv1.setText(""+(int) (millisUntilFinished/1000));

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Handler handler=new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            start();
                        }
                    },1000);

                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just keep track of the number of times it finished like so

```
  final Context cntx=this;
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             int num_rounds=0;
             try {
                 num_rounds = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
             }catch (Exception ex){
                 Toast.makeText(cntx,"Invalid Integer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             return;}
             if(num_rounds==0)
             {
                 return;
             }
            final int[] round_count = {0};
            final int finalNum_rounds = num_rounds;
            CountDownTimer countDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    tv1.setText(""+(int) (millisUntilFinished/1000));

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    round_count[0]++;
                    if(round_count[0] < finalNum_rounds){
                        Handler handler=new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                start();
                            }
                        },1000);
                    }



                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your code is working but I have two questions. Is this fragment of code "try {
                 num_rounds = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
             }catch (Exception ex){
                 Toast.makeText(cntx,"Invalid Integer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             return;}
             if(num_rounds==0)
             {" Is necessary because when  I delete it this code doesn't work correctly. And second do you know how to display how many rounds are left for example after 3 rounds of 10 on display i will get "3/10"

Comment: its necessary to validate the input from the Edittext to ensure no null or non numeric characters.Secondly,yes it is possible by changing "tv1.setText(""+(int) (millisUntilFinished/1000));" to "     tv1.setText((round_count[0]+1)+"/"+finalNum_rounds+"   "+(int) (millisUntilFinished/1000));
                   "

Comment: But I have one question. Namely when I set for example 3 rounds after first break display jump from 1/3 to 3/3

Comment: Can I have ask to you?

Comment: Its very important pls answer me as quick as it possible

Comment: Or it is possible start private chat

Comment: But I have different question. When I set number of rounds after round I have 5 seconds of break and I would like to show number of rounds like that for ex. 1/3. And I have problem because for example when I set 3 rounds and these rounds will pass my countdown timer counts as many breaks as there are rounds when I would like to have -1 rounds compared to the number of round

Comment: Could you help me

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by remember the number of times the CountDown timer is elapsed. Use a class variable for this:

```
int mNbOfRounds= 0;
```

Then before restarting your timer check the value of this variable and don't restart your timer if the number of rounds exceed your value:

```
@Override
public void onFinish() {
if( mNbRounds <= MAX_NB_ROUNDS_VALUE )
    {
    Handler handler=new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {start(); }},1000);

    }
    //Don't forget to increment the nb of rounds:
    mNbOfRounds+= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First make a integer within the class scope, get value from edittext and reduce by 1 on finish of countdown:

```
    Button btn1;
    TextView tv1;

    EditText et1;
    int totalRounds;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1=findViewById(R.id.textView);
        btn1=findViewById(R.id.button);
        et1=findViewById(R.id.editText);


        //String edit1=et1.getText().toString();
        //number of rounds



        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                totalRounds = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
                CountDownTimer countDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        tv1.setText(""+(int) (millisUntilFinished/1000));

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                           totalRounds--;
                        if(totalRounds>0) {
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    start();
                                }
                            }, 1000);
                        }
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
    }
```